# How to hide ion tabs for inner pages?

Tags: angular7, ionic4, angular7-router

I am using ionic 4 with angular 7. I am trying to leverage [ion-tabs](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/tabs)
I want to know how can we hide tab bar for inner routes or pages.

After searching on google I have figured there was a way in ionic 3 to add a property "tabsHideOnSubPages: true" in configurations during bootstrapping but I am unable to find same for ionic 4.

```
const routes: Routes = [
  {
    path: 'tabs',
    component: tabsPage,
    children: [
      {
        path: '',
        redirectTo: '/tabs/tab1',
        pathMatch: 'full'
      },
      {
        path: 'tab1',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: Tab1Page
          },
          { // want to hide tab bar for this particular route.
            path: ':tabDetailId', 
            component: Tab1DetailPage
          } 
        ]
      },
      {
        path: 'tab2',
        children: [
          {
            path: '',
            component: Tab2Page
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
];
```

I want to hide the tab bar on inner pages for example  "domain/tabs/tab1/1"

Comment: This is for ionic [4](https://medium.com/@JordanBenge/ionic-4-hiding-showing-tabs-on-certain-pages-31cf2380a5db)

Comment: @Péttrin Miranda, is this the best practice for hiding tab bar on inner pages?

Comment: probably yet is the best solution.

Answer (score 0):

try to replace this:

{ // want to hide tab bar for this particular route.
path: ':tabDetailId',
component: Tab1DetailPage
}

to "app-routing.module.ts" it works for me